# How to split a String and compare with a Column that String is present or not in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting a String like below

```
'.NET Framework','JAVA J2EE'
```

Now I need to check with the a column `Skillset` that any one of the above is present in that column or not and need to return those values of the Column.

Please help how can I do this in mysql.

Comment: So both values from above string are present in your column?

Comment: Don't you know how to use `'Like'` ?

Comment: I tried using IN and FIND_IN_SET.But those will return the column values which eaxctly matches with the String parts like '.NET Framework' or 'JAVA J2EE'.But it's not returning the columns whose values like '.NET Framework,C#','JAVA J2EE,J2ME'.I need to get these values also.

Comment: @Ravinder I know Like it will not useful in my situtation.If you can do this using Like.Please post the query.I think LIKE is to check that column will preset a value like.But requirement here is different.

Comment: Could you show some sample data and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: @shree.pat18 may or maynot present in the column.If any one values present in tha column then I need to return those column values.

Comment: You really should avoid having columns with comma-separated lists of values. Use a many-to-many relation table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some R&D,I found one solution for this.I did like below:

```
SELECT *, skillset FROM tresume_mas WHERE skillset REGEXP '.NET Framework|JAVA J2EE';
```

Comment: Regular expressions recognize metacharacters, like that vertical bar you included. The period (dot character) is a metacharacter that matches _any_ single character. To search for literal **`.NET`**, and not match other strings, like **`xNET`**, you'd need to escape that dot with a backslash, **`\.NET`**. There are several other metacharacters that would need to be escaped, to guarantee this approach will "work".

Answer (score 0):

Split your input string on comma, and make a `FIND_IN_SET` expression from each of the substrings, and combine them with `OR`.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE FIND_IN_SET("'.NET Framework'", Skillset) OR FIND_IN_SET("'JAVA J2EE'", Skillset)
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2244b/2)

Here's how you would code it in PHP for any number of input strings:

```
$skill_array = array();
foreach (explode(',', $skills) as $skill) {
    $skill_array[] = 'FIND_IN_SET("' . $skill . '")';
}
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE ' . implode(' OR ', $skill_array);
```

Comment: It will work for any number. Just keep adding more `OR` expressions for each of them. Do it in a loop.

Comment: You write a `for` loop in the program that's creating the SQL.

Comment: I am passing the String to a SP using CallableStatement. If the value is not null I am concatenating this to a Query in SP.

Comment: You can write a `WHILE` loop in the stored procedure that splits the string on the commas. It's more complicated than scripting languages like PHP or Python, since it doesn't have a built-in function, but you can do it. I suggest you google for it.